How to convey a music album that traverses the listener through ambisonic space arriving to each "SONG" (stereo/non spatial)/sound souce?
Im reframing how to present my next album to the listener......(Incoming Laymen)
Imagine you're hearing stereo audio file "Song 1/Track" this POV is  non spatial, .wav .mp3 audio file.  Approaching the end said song/audio will now be crossfaded/mixed to being a playback sound source in an ambisonic recording space. Basically, normal Audio is now being heard coming from a phone/tv/radio in a space captured by room mic.
Now, you the listener/room mic will move away from  "Song1 source" and eventually come closer to the sound source for Song 2.
Here will need to blend back into Stereo. These tranisitional ambisonic versions for the songs can come in various forms, Playback devices, Actual instruments, spoken words or overall creative engagement with the space, mic, and sound source, and motion.
I have a Zoom H3-VR 360 mic, capable of 4 tracks and a line out, Binural, Stereo, Mono, and other standard audio mics 57 58 Condesn etc.  I set out to convey this through audio only, so any cool insights would be greatly appreciated and credited in the work, if you would like. Thanks!

So, are you trying to make a “spatial crossfade” to your songs?

Yes crossfading from non spatial(songs)--->to spatial (between songs)--->non spatial (songs)----etc I am also down to center the songs/non head tracking while the other channels are headtracked.

You can certainly cross fade between songs and spatial stagings. The easiest way would probably to mock this up in a real room with two playback systems. So you would have 4 recordings:

Song 1 dry stereo
Song 1 in room
Song 2 in room
Song 2 dry stereo

You can line them all up in your DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) and experiment with different crossfade times and profiles.
You can choose the "in room" recordings to have same or different room, playback systems, source/mic location, playback technology etc. You can certainly do more than one version and, again, use your DAW to compare and optimize.
In-room recordings are tricky to make: you want to carefully control background noise, strong reflections, buzzes and rattle, stay away from pronounced room modes, etc. Chances are you will have to do a decent amount of postprocessing to spectrally match them (and time align them too). Time alignment is easy but spectral matching takes a fair bit of experience (and suitable tools).
Alternatively you can try to find measured stereo room impulse responses online and produce the "in room" recordings through convolution.

Thanks so much Hilmar! I definitely understand and equipped to capture these 4 tracks as you instructed. Does "pronounced room modes" describe a room with sub optimal/zero sound treatment? i.e. a gymnasium, tile bathroom, big/small with lots of reflective surfaces? Time aligning I can manage, but this 1st time hearing "spectrally match" the room. I looked around but any more elaboration on this would be great. I'm also assuming convolution with IR's means Song 1 in room through these IRs in my DAW?

A big part of the transitions will be the microphone moving away/towards the next Song/Sound Source. I have a 360 ambisonic microphone, I'm assuming Ill just add this to the two forms you have laid out nicely for me.  1. Stereo Audio 2. Room/Alternate Sound Source 3. Ambisonic Mic moving to different versions of Room/Alt Sounds. I am wondering about the spectral matching when it comes to the moving ambisonic mic. I assume I would have to match them as well, or match both somehow since it would be entering both room/spatial settings.

@sHredVaN: hard to tell without listening to the recordings. My guess you want to spectrally match the spatially averaged energy over the entire moving microphone path but depending on room, mic path and speaker setup, that may or may not be "good enough".
